# AsyncTask doInBackground returns too soon

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` connecting to a websocket.

```
protected Void doInBackground() { 
  client.connect();
  return null;
}
```

When it's finished attempting the connection, I want the following to happen (currently inside `onPostExecute`):

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
  if (socketConnected) {
    doOtherThings();
  } else {
    log("Failed to connect.");
  }
```

I've also tossed in the following, as another probe of sorts (in the `WebSocketClient` implementation):

```
public void onOpen() {
  log("Opened successfully!");
  socketConnected = true;
}
```

The `onPostExecute` method prints the failure message , followed by the success message from `onOpen`. This suggests that `doInBackground` is returning too soon. Is there any common reason this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, probably the method client.connect() creates a ASyncTask and this leaves your task to continue executation, ending the method and going to onPostExecute.

If thats the case, the API you are using does should have some methods to listening async messages.
The API should have some Listener or Callback that will be fired at your thread.

EDIT: I searched WebViewClient on internet and the method connect() does indeed creates a new Thread, you should look how to use the calls properly.

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence?